# storing 1,2,3,4 numbers with comma into DB

Tags: php

I was used implode function for an array to insert the value into DB.

```
$day1=implode(',',$day);
echo "day:".$day1;
```

$day have a value of array like {100,100}; now i change this like 100,100 string to insert into the table. because I can't store array directly into the table.if any option instead of implode() to load the array into DB please post that.
else help me which datatype is used to store in DB . i cann't use int because of commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption you are using MySQl, you should be utilizing the TEXT data type, because this data type offers no assumptions on what size your insert will be. Now, of course if you want to calculate a fixed length, feel free to use varchar, but because of the unknown width of your numbers, you would have to overallocate regardless.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html

Storing it as a string with numbers delimited by a comma is an adequate storage format, and should work fine, as you are dealing with numbers there would be no conflict when retrieving the data and then exploding the value back into an array using the same comma delimiter.

Comment: if i encode the value in json like above example which is best DT to use.

Comment: Same as above, JSON is just an easier way to structure objects into text. CSV is completely valid for your particular use case.

Answer (score 1):

The implode() returns the array items concatenated to a single string (http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).
Your database field needs to be of a text type (char, varchar, text) to store the value.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you have to convert array into json and store in db.
ex:

```
$data=("a","b","c");
$json_encode=json_encode($data);
```

then after retrieved from db convert back to array.

ex:

```
$json_decode=json_decode($data,true);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's worked. then can I use integer datatype if the value is 1,2,3 in an array?. Which DT has used in DB Table Vaibhav S.

Answer (score 0):

$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');

$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone

// Empty string when using an empty array:
var_dump(implode('hello', array())); // string(0) ""